# Plot observations along time per column (data availability)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have a dataframe that contains daily dates and several stations, within the stations there are days that don't have a measurements but the dates are complete. I made some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', periods = 24, freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':rng,'Stn1':np.random.randn(len(rng)),'Stn2':np.random.randn(len(rng)),'Stn3':np.random.randn(len(rng))  })
df.loc[df['Stn1'] > 1,'Stn1'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Stn2'] < -1,'Stn2'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Stn3'] > 0,'Stn3'] = np.nan
```

And this is what it looks:

```
         Date      Stn1      Stn2      Stn3
0  1980-01-01       NaN  2.269755 -1.613898
1  1980-01-02  0.400157       NaN -0.212740
2  1980-01-03  0.978738  0.045759 -0.895467
3  1980-01-04       NaN -0.187184       NaN
4  1980-01-05       NaN  1.532779 -0.510805
5  1980-01-06 -0.977278  1.469359 -1.180632
6  1980-01-07  0.950088  0.154947 -0.028182
7  1980-01-08 -0.151357  0.378163       NaN
8  1980-01-09 -0.103219 -0.887786       NaN
9  1980-01-10  0.410599       NaN       NaN
10 1980-01-11  0.144044 -0.347912 -0.634322
11 1980-01-12       NaN  0.156349 -0.362741
12 1980-01-13  0.761038  1.230291 -0.672460
13 1980-01-14  0.121675  1.202380 -0.359553
14 1980-01-15  0.443863 -0.387327 -0.813146
15 1980-01-16  0.333674 -0.302303 -1.726283
16 1980-01-17       NaN       NaN       NaN
17 1980-01-18 -0.205158       NaN -0.401781
18 1980-01-19  0.313068       NaN -1.630198
19 1980-01-20 -0.854096  1.950775       NaN
20 1980-01-21 -2.552990 -0.509652 -0.907298
21 1980-01-22  0.653619 -0.438074       NaN
22 1980-01-23  0.864436       NaN       NaN
23 1980-01-24 -0.742165  0.777490       NaN
```

What I want to do, is to obtain something like this:

[image]

On the X axis there are the dates, and along the Y axis there is each station and the dates in which each one got measurements, so when the station has NaN there's a gap. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import datetime
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

n = 3 # number of stations
stns = ['']
for i in range(n):
    stn = 'Stn' + str(i+1)
    stns.append(stn)
    df.loc[~np.isnan(df[stn]), stn] = i+1
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
dates = df.Date
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
ax = df.plot(legend=False)
ax.set_yticks(range(n+1))
ax.set_yticklabels(stns)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(dates)))
ax.set_xticklabels(dates, rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Yes! Like that. But if I have more stations I'd have to put it whitin a for loop right?

Comment: Updated the post with more generic solution @Ann M

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to change the NAN with something else, or remove them at all.

You can use this [link here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to drop NAN values.

Comment: But I don't want to remove the Nan's, I want to keep where each station does not have measurement

Comment: you can change them with a very known and clear value to you, and then do a if statement and keep those values.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('1980-01-01', periods = 24, freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':rng,'Stn1':np.random.randn(len(rng)),'Stn2':np.random.randn(len(rng)),'Stn3':np.random.randn(len(rng))  })
df.loc[df['Stn1'] > 1,'Stn1'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Stn2'] < -1,'Stn2'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Stn3'] > 0,'Stn3'] = np.nan

df = df.set_index('Date')

for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[col].loc[~df[col].isnull()] = i+1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (15, 5), dpi=300)
p = sns.pointplot(y=0,x='Date', data=df1, hue='level_1')
ax.set_ylabel('')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[0:], labels=labels[0:])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
p.set(yticklabels=[]);
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hello, I tried running your code. However I noticed that in p=sns.pointplot(..., in data there's a "df1". I change it to df. However I get an error that says "ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Date'". Do you know how to fix it?